# How to configure the directfb instead opengl in cobalt display configuration

Tags: cobalt

We need to configure the graphics backend of cobalt instead using opengl(EGL) , Is there possible to configure the directfb instead opengl. How to enable the directfb instead opengl.

Answer (score 0):

Support for DirectFB was deprecated in Cobalt 21 due to the fact that DirectFB itself is mostly discontinued and unsupported.

If you want to build Cobalt with DirectFB, you may check out Starboard implementation for Linux with DirectFB support from Cobalt 20: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/refs/heads/20.lts.1+/src/starboard/linux/x64directfb/.